# node program run in cli using node index.js! Edge-js works but when running after converting into exe using pkg package memory corrupt error comes?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, edgejs, node-pkg

I have written a node program in which edge-js package is being used and it works pretty well when running it directly through the `node index.js` command but afterwards when i convert the program to .exe file using pkg package and upon running the compiled exe the following error comes:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at V8SynchronizationContext.Initialize()
```

The executale should run exactly in the same way the program runs through cli command